# how to separate value in list into a different list?

Tags: list, python-2.7, indexing, split, tuples

this is the list into a list of tuple.

```
tup_new_lst = [[('A', '10'), ('B', '28D'), ('C', '14')], 
              [('B', '49C'), ('C', 'T26')],
               [('A', '24K'), ('C', 'B28'), ('D', '54C')]]
```

Here i need separate the value base on follow format:

```
A: ['10','NaN','24K']
B: ['28D','49C','NaN']
C: ['14','T26','B28']
D: ['NaN','NaN','54C']
```

In this list of list. there in second list there No A's tuple.

I have done this following code for identify A's one:

```
 a_lst = []
 for tup_lst in tup_new_lst:
     for a in tup_lst:
        if a[0] == 'A':
           a_lst.append(a[1])
     else:
        a_lst.append('NaN')
 print(a_lst)
```

Output is:

```
 ['10', 'NaN', 'NaN', '24K', 'NaN']
```

desired output:

```
 ['10','NaN','24K']
```

Anyone please give support.

Comment: looks like your indentation is wrong for the else, it is matched with `for a in tup_list` not `if a[0] == 'A':`

Comment: can please you correct the code below

Answer (score 1):

You may add a boolean to record if you found your reserched element in the list and append NaN to the list if not found as there:

```
a_lst = []
for tup_lst in tup_new_lst:
  found = False
  for a in tup_lst:
    if a[0] == 'A':
      a_lst.append(a[1])
      found = True
  if not found:
    a_lst.append('NaN')
print(a_lst)
```